# KnockoutJS set value of input

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to clear the value in an `input` after an ajax function is ran. I am using a simple function: `$('input[name=foo]').val('')`. The input clears but the button (which is enabled or disabled based on the number of chars in the input) does not disable again:

**The JS:**

```
function viewModel(){
  var self = this;

  //input
  self.foo = ko.observable("");
  self.eightChars = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    return self.foo().length > 7;       
  });  

  //button
  self.enable = ko.observable("");
  self.enableOk = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    return self.eightChars();       
  });  
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**The HTML:**

```
<input type='text' name='foo' placeholder='Foo' autocomplete='off' data-bind='textInput:foo'>
<button type="button" data-bind='enable:self.enableOk()'>Save</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout's [`textInput`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html) binding is a two-way binding, so to clear the input's value, clear the knockout observable that it's bound to.

So it's as simple as:

```
self.foo('');
```

Answer (score 4):

When the observable will be notified after the `change` event was triggered so to do this try to change the value like this:

```
$('input[name=foo]').val('').change();
```

> **Or** you can set the value of the observable directily and not the input `val`, but you need the correct scope to do this.

```
self.foo('');
```

> **Note**: Some dev's use your approach, that access the DOM element  to clear it as a workaround. So the best approach is use the observable property, because that what the MVVM do.